# When distributing a Java-written application to multiple users, how do I reference a common directory that is unique to each user?

Tags: java, directory

**Disclaimer:**
*I know that this is something that is covered very early in learning Java, however, I am just a hobbyist and I am self-taught. I am only as good as the information I find online is. Please do not be derisive or condescending. We were all new at one time.*

As mentioned, I have a written a Java Form app. What it does it takes user input and writes it to an Excel file. How can I *dynamically* reference a file (the Excel, in particular) that is on each users' computer, found in a different directory but not have to hardcode each user's exact file path and distribute individually?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't unless you know that each user has an exact same (relative) path to the file.

Comment: You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the user's home directory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey user.dir is current working directory, not home directory.

Comment: @MK, good point.  `user.dir` may also be an option, but `user.home` is likely to be a better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`user.home` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Which will give you, say, `c:\users\mk`

and then you can append your path to that.

Comment: What I did was grab the 'user.home' property and then used 'mkdir()' to create a new path and then did a 'file.createNewFile()' to create a new file in the new directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have the application ask the user for the path.

Comment: Indeed. Now, let me ask another question: which is more advisable for the developer, to distribute the app and let the user know to place the Excel file in their Documents folder or to create an object and have the user define that object via user input?

Comment: @Rincewind I would pop up a widget asking for the file location but I would prefill the widget with a default location. I believe that is more user friendly to ask where the file is rather then tell the user where to place the file. This is the type of discussion you should have with your users. Either way I think that the file location should be something the user can configure.

Comment: I have decided to do exactly that. I'll use a text file as a database to store the directory and the user will establish said directory when they run the widget (JOptionPane). My knowledge and experience is limited, but, is using a text file and JOptionPane bad ways of doing that?

Comment: @Rincewind I don't have a lot of Java GUI experience so I cant speak to your JOptionPane question. There *might* be a better option than a text file, but is should work well enough. You might want to use a common format, within you text file, such as XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the application configuration have the user define an environment variable using a known name with either the desired directory or the install directory (then use the variable to derive the desired directory).

for example:

1. tell the user to define BLAMMY_HOME which contains the install location of your software (named BLAMMY).
2. derive the desired directory by concatinating the value of BLAMMY_HOME and "/desired/directory/name".

or

1. have the user define BLAMMY_SPOT which contains the full path the the desired directory.
2. use the value of BLAMMY_SPOT in your application.

Defaulting to using user.home is fine, but I (personally) do not like that technique (as a user).

Comment: What is the best way to hold that new directory after the user inputs it? The '.close()' dumps everything that isn't hard coded when the app closes.

Answer (score 1):

Take an example of 2 users

```
UserA path: /opt/file/directories/target (contains the excel file)
UserB path: /opt/directories/target (contains the excel file)
```

There's absolutely no way to find the `target` directory (except searching for it, but then you might find another one) unless the application has access to some out of band information.  For example, Java offers the `user.home` property

```
String pathPrefix = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

so you can use that and make your target directory relative to that.

That's the whole purpose of applications having installation/working directories. As another example, take the Windows Registry. Imagine you had to download a patch from the internet. The patch itself wouldn't be able to check all the paths on the file system until it found yours (each user has a different one). Instead, it can find that path from the Windows Registry (or something comparable depending on the application).

Comment: When it gets to searching the registry and other search methods, it becomes too convoluted to establish just a directory. I did not know about the user.home, though. Thanks! +1

Comment: @RinceWind You're welcome. My point with the registry example was that without establishing some checkpoint, you can't orient your application. That's what the `user.home` property does.